# How to regulate CollectionViewCell size, by code or by storyBoard(CollectionView is inside of TableView)

Tags: swift

[image: Runned Project]
[image: //My CollectionView sizes]
[image: //My TableView sizes]

I have collectionView Inside `UITableViewCell`, and in `UICollectionViewCell` I have `UImageView`, when I run the project there are some free space, which i don't want: how can I fix it(by code or by storyboard - it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix it by code. You can manage space between two `UICollectionView` cells by using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

Provide the cell height and width in the above method.

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

The above method use for a vertically scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between successive rows. For a horizontally scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between successive columns.